# Pandas Get Sequence of 1s and 0s Given Strings

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['K','1','1,2,3']})
df
       a
0      K
1      1
2  1,2,3
```

I would like to convert the values in column a to a corresponding sequence of 1s and 0s given this map:

```
K 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If a value is present, a 1 is put in place of a 0.
If the value is not present, the place is held by a 0.
If no value is present, the sequence would be a string of 6 0s.

So "K" would be:
100000

And "1,2,3" would be:
011100

Desired result:

```
       a       b
0      K  100000
1      1  010000
2  1,2,3  011100
```

I tried `pd.get_dummies(df['a'])`, but it that only works where there is only 1 character in the cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how exactly the mapping works? I don't understand how it works from the current description.

Comment: Sure; please see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question well, but you can use `.apply()` with custom map:

```
m = {'K': 1 << 0,
     '1': 1 << 1,
     '2': 1 << 2, 
     '3': 1 << 3,
     '4': 1 << 4,
     '5': 1 << 5}
    
df['b'] = df.a.apply(
        lambda x: '{:06b}'.format(sum(m[v] for v in x.split(',')))[::-1]
    )
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       a       b
0      K  100000
1      1  010000
2  1,2,3  011100
```

Comment: What if I wanted '1' from the second row to have a '3' instead like this?
030000 instead of 010000?

Comment: @DanceParty2 Can you explain more? Do you want only this value from second row to have `3` instead of `1`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And 1, 2, 3 would produce 031100.

Comment: New question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318415/pandas-get-sequence-of-integers-and-0s-given-strings

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `get_dummies` then `reindex`

```
s = df.a.str.get_dummies(',').reindex(columns=['K','1','2','3','4','5'],fill_value=0).astype(str).agg(''.join,1)
0    100000
1    010000
2    011100
dtype: object
df['b'] = s
```