# Pandas Get Sequence of integers and 0s Given Strings

Tags: python, pandas

[Related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287044/pandas-get-sequence-of-1s-and-0s-given-strings),

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['K','1','1,2,3']})
df
       a
0      K
1      1
2  1,2,3
```

I would like to convert the values in column a to a corresponding sequence of 1s and 0s given this map:

```
K 1 2 3 4 5
1 3 1 1 1 1
```

If a value is present, a 1 is put in place of a 0 (but a 3 is used instead of a 1 for the value of 1). If the value is not present, the place is held by a 0. If no value is present, the sequence would be a string of 6 0s.

So "K" would be: 100000

And "1,2,3" would be: 031100

Desired result:

```
       a       b
0      K  100000
1      1  030000
2  1,2,3  031100
```

Both current answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287044/pandas-get-sequence-of-1s-and-0s-given-strings) work great for replacing 0s with 1s, but I just need to add a layer to replace 0s with 3s for specific values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the value of `b` is `010000` when `a=1` and not `030000`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
d={'K':'1', '1':'3', '2':'1', '3':'1', '4':'1', '5':'1'}

def f(s):
    return ''.join([d[i] if i in s else '0' for i in d])

df['b']=df['a'].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
       a       b
0      K  100000
1      1  030000
2  1,2,3  031100
```